# What does it mean that a stock rallies by a straight line?

Tags: stocks

A text reads

> the stock price rallies by 1.2 % every day on a straight line

What, exactly, does that mean? Does the spot rise with 1.2% every day? If so, 1.2% of what? 1.2% of the previous day's price, or of the initial day 1 price?

Or does the spot move 1.2% every day in a random direction?

Comment: Can you link to the text?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's a line in some hand-out notes.

Comment: The suggestion is that the stock price increases every day by 1.2%, without any exceptions, so that if you were to plot the daily price movements on a chart, you would get a straight line upwards.  In fact you would plot a parabolic line due to the compounding effect on price movements.

Comment: Yes, it's the "straight line" part I don't understand. Usually, by "rallies", it means it increases. But how does it increase on a "straight line" if it's 1.2 % every day? If that's 1.2 % of the current spot price, then there's no straight line, it's a convex growth.

Comment: Yes, "convex" or parabolic.  It is common in financial journalism to describe an asset price that consistently moves in one direction as "moving in a straight line".  It is not meant to be taken literally, rather to suggest consistent movement.

Comment: Or if you graphed the return as a percentage, it would be a straight (horizontal) line.  But it seems like you should be asking whoever made the comment what they meant.

Comment: SensIble charts of stock prices use a logarithmic axis for the price. 1.2% growth per day is a straight line on a logarithmic graph.

Answer (score 1):

> What, exactly, does that mean?

"Rallies" implies that it is increasing every day. Increasing by 1.2% of the first day's price would imply that the total price is increasing on a straight line.  Increasing by 1.2% of the previous day's price would imply that the daily percent change is a straight, level line. It's impossible to know which the source is describing, but it is typical to talk about percent change on a daily basis.

Comment: Could you expand on the following: "the daily percent change is increasing on a straight line". The daily percent change is 1.2 % - always. So how is it increasing?

Comment: @Mahi I was envisioning a chart of percent change vs time which changed linearly. Not sure I put that into words though

Comment: If you plot price against time, and the stock price increases by 1.2% of the previous day's price, the result is not a straight line. It will be an exponential curve (although a very flat one).

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes, you could plot total price as a curve or percent change as a straight line

Comment: @DJClayworth semilog graph paper is my friend.